# $f$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We know that if $f \in \mathcal R[a,b]$ and if $a = c_0 < c_1<\cdots<c_m =b$, then the restrictions of $f$ to each subinterval $[c_{i-1},c_i]$ are Riemann integrable.

Is the converse true, i.e if $f ; [a,b] \to \Bbb R$, and $a = c_0 < c_1<\cdots<c_m =b$ and that the restrictions of $f$ to each subinterval $[c_{i-1},c_i]$ belong to $\mathcal R[c_{i-1},c_i]$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable?

I am finding difficult to show this.

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[c_{i-1},c_i]$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P_i$ of it such that $U(f,P_i)-L(f,P_i)< \epsilon/m$. If you use the partitions $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^m$ to create a partition of $[a,b]$ in the obvious way, you're done.

Comment: taking unions??

Comment: @tone Indeed. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Must be true. Probably easiest to show that if $f$ is not Riemann integrable over some $[c_{i-1},c_i]$, then it is not integrable over $[a,b]$.